# asp.net function depends on the time

Tags: asp.net, datetime, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to schedule tasks in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752326/best-way-to-schedule-tasks-in-c-sharp)

I have a function that sends notification when user click Save button in popup. In this popup user else enters date and time. What i need, that this notification sends in time that user entered. Do you know any time depends methods? Thanks very much!

Comment: Is the notification an email? And do you need to set the sent-time of the email to the time the user entered? Please clarify your requirements - they are very vague at the moment. Please also show your current code. Finally, please review http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions on asking questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to schedule tasks in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752326/best-way-to-schedule-tasks-in-c-sharp), [Schedule email in asp.net c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401517/schedule-email-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: are you sure that till that time user not going to break connection or refresh page what about in that case

Comment: not, i'm not sure. User can enter notification time for example tomorrow at 9pm. So i need post this notification into application exactly at that time. What i need it just solution that run my working code at time, that entered user in popup.